# How can I make 2 dimensional arraylist with split in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

String s = "0,0,0,0,0\n,0,0,0,0,0\n,0,0,0,0,0\n,0,0,0,0,0\n,0,0,0,0,0\n";

this is the result that I expect.

```
00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

I need to make 2D **arraylist**.

I tried this:

```
    String temp = s;
    String[] tempRow = temp.split("\n");

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mat = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    for(int i = 0; i<tempRow.length; i++){
        ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>(tempRow.length);
        String[] a = s.split(",");

        String[] b = a[i].split("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j<tempRow.length;j++){
            row.add(a[i]);
        }
        mat.add(row);
    }
```

but splitting "," didn't work.

is there any correct way to make 2 dimensional arraylist?

Comment: I don't think there's a "convenient" way of doing it.  Using a loop like you have is probably the only/preferred way.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Be precise when something doesn't work. Create a [mcve], showcase the problem with examples and add the full error message/description.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach is a little bit off, instead, it should be as follows:

```
List<List<String>> accumulator = new ArrayList<>();
for (String str : s.split("\n")) {
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String e : str.split(","))
        if (!e.isEmpty())
            tempList.add(e);
    accumulator.add(tempList);
}
```

or using the stream API, one could go with:

```
List<List<String>> result = Pattern.compile("\n")
                .splitAsStream(s)
                .map(e -> Arrays.stream(e.split(","))
                           .filter(a -> !a.isEmpty()).collect(toList()))
                .collect(toList());
```

The latter solution requires the following import:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```

Comment: @Vasan let's assume you did that and went with `for (String str : s.split("\n"))
            accumulator.add(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));` this would result in `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]` instead of `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]` hence why I am using the inner loop to filter out the blank elements.

Comment: @Aomine Right, missed the empty check.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

The reason why your approach does not work is because you are representing your data in a `String` like:

```
0,0,0,0,0\n
,0,0,0,0,0\n
,0,0,0,0,0\n
,0,0,0,0,0\n
,0,0,0,0,0
```

Note the **leading commas**. But in your code you split on `\n` where the real correct line separator is `\n,` instead. Either split by `\n,` or remove the leading commas from the data format:

```
0,0,0,0,0\n
0,0,0,0,0\n
0,0,0,0,0\n
0,0,0,0,0\n
0,0,0,0,0
```

Also, you are first splitting by `,` and then by `\n`. But that's the wrong way around. You want to first split all lines and then the entries in those lines. Else you get

```
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0\n", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0\n", ...]
```

for the first split and then

```
[
    ["0"],
    ["0"],
    ["0"],
    ["0"],
    ["0"],
    ["0"],
    ...
]
```

for the second split. Fix it by splitting the other way around. First the lines:

```
["0,0,0,0,0", "0,0,0,0,0", ...]
```

and then the entries:

```
[
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    ...
]
```

---

### Parsing

Java does not have a built-in method to do this. You should approach this like you already did. That is, by manually splitting, iterating and collecting:

```
String outerDelimiter = "\n";
String innerDelimiter = ",";
String input = ...

List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

for (String line : input.split(outerDelimiter)) {
    List<Integer> lineData = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String data : line.split(innerDelimiter)) {
        lineData.add(Integer.valueOf(data));
    }
    result.add(lineData);
}
```

Or if you want `int[][]`:

```
List<int[]> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

for (String line : input.split(outerDelimiter)) {
    String[] lineDataText = line.split(innerDelimiter);
    int[] lineData = new int[lineDataText.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < lineDataText.length; i++) {
        lineData[i] = Integer.valueOf(lineDataText[i]);
    }
    result.add(lineData);
}

int[][] result = resultList.toArray(new int[resultList.size()][]);
```

Pack it inside an utility method and its comfortable to use:

```
int[][] data = parseData(input, outerDelimiter, innerDelimiter);
```

---

### Stream API

Alternatively you can use the Stream API:

```
int[][] result = Arrays.stream(input.split(outerDelimiter))  // Stream<String>
    .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(innerDelimiter))   // Stream<String[]>
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)                          // Stream<IntStream>
        .toArray())                                          // Stream<int[]>
    .toArray(int[][]::new);                                  // int[][]
```

Comment: this would yield a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` if you don't filter out empty elements.

Comment: @Aominè Yes. Was this a requirement of OP that I overlooked?

Comment: @Aominè Now I see the problem. Adjusted the answer, thanks.

Comment: That's definitely an improvement to your previous description, although not sure what you're parsing the data when all the OP wants is a `List<List<String>>`? this could be because the data is not always a valid integer or that's simply how they want it. nevertheless, let's not assume and go with your current approach of parsing the strings to integers, your code would still fail as you're attempting to parse empty strings to integers so adding a filter as such `.filter(e -> !e.isEmpty())` in the inner stream should suffice and same goes for the imperative approach.

Comment: @Aominè I still don't see why this would be necessary. I mean you are right. But did OP hint that his data will contain empty entries at all? I assumed it does not.

Comment: The OP has provided this `String s = "0,0,0,0,0\n,0,0,0,0,0\n,0,0,0,0,0\n,0,0,0,0,0\n,0,0,0,0,0\n";` in their post  as the input string and if you run your code when `s` is the `input` string it fails. this is where i am getting to.

Comment: @Aominè Only because of the leading commas. I addressed this in the first paragraph. The real line separator is `\n,` and not `\n`. But I think the input shouldn't contain the leading commas at all. The format should be changed, if allowed. But yeah, now I get your comment, thanks.